# What are the warp nacelle fins for

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise, warp

The Enterprise, both TOS, DIS and Kelvin has 3 fins on the back of its nacelles. On the Kelvin-Enterprise, these actually open when the ship goes to warp, much like the deflector. But while the deflector aleays had a very clear purpose, I don't think I've ever heard anyone mention the fins, especially since they dissapeared in TNG. So, I'd love to know wether there are canon mentions of these fins.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some pictures, please? And highlight those fins somehow?  I am not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: I think he means the parts labelled as "light grey intercooler" in this model painting guide.  https://culttvman.com/main/a-modelers-guide-to-painting-the-starship-enterprise-pt2-by-gary-kerr/

Comment: You can see the fins easily on the Kelvin timeline Enterprise--when it is preparing to go to warp, the fins will rise up.

Comment: @Pete You're right--they're called "intercoolers" on blueprints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "warp fins," as some people call them, seem to be [intercoolers](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Intercooler). They serve as a cooling system for the warp engines. You can see a pair of fins at the end of each nacelle on the TOS Enterprise in the link provided by Pete in the comments and the [blueprint below (from Cygnus X-1)](https://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/constitution-class-starship.php):

[image]

They are labeled as the "Post-Stage Flux **Intercooler** Assembly" (item no. 16). You can also see the fins clearly on the [newly updated (again) *DISCO* Enterprise](https://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/discovery-era-enterprise.php).

Another sheet from the same blueprints, however, shows that the fins are "Post-Stage Flux Tuners" (item no. 28):

[image]

The *Star Trek* reboot people really decided to emphasize the fins (for some reason), so they stand out (literally) when the Enterprise goes to warp:

[image]

This is what you were describing when you said that the fins/intercoolers "open."

After the original Enterprise, the intercooler fins disappear. The Excelsior class does have fins on its nacelles, but they are not intercoolers.
Although the intercooler *fins* disappear, the intercoolers are not gone, but placed elsewhere in the nacelle. The "engine intercoolers" (item no. 9) are shown in the Enterprise-D blueprint below:

[image]

So the fins seem to have served primarily as warp engine intercoolers before the fins were removed and the intercoolers were moved.